# BCryptPasswordEncoder Spring Security not defining

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Hi I develop a Spring Boot app (v1.5.18.BUILD-SNAPSHOT), but this fails when I try to start the app....

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.eficacia.security.WebSecurity required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder' in your configuration.
```

The problem is that I have the bean configured:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

In my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

WebSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({"com.eficacia.security"})
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String USER_REGISTRATION_URL = "/v1/user";

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, USER_REGISTRATION_URL).permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        //configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://opusclick.com","https://gateway2.tucompra.com.co"));
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","PATCH","DELETE"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

WebConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public WebMvcConfiguration(ApplicationContext applicationContext, EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().applicationContext(this.applicationContext).build();
        argumentResolvers.add(new DTOModelMapper(objectMapper, entityManager));
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
            JacksonMapperConfiguration jacksonMapperConfiguration= new JacksonMapperConfiguration();
        converters.add(jacksonMapperConfiguration.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

My question is very simple, and that is why the definition of the class *'org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder*' is not found if there really exists a configuration class for this.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your web configurer class isn't in the package `com.eficacia.security` or one of its subpackages.

Move `WebMvcConfiguration` in a place within the `@ComponentScan`ed packages.

Comment: Ok, what you mean is that you move the WebMvcConfiguration class inside the com.eficacia.security package ?

Comment: @AlejoDev Yes, move it inside the `com.eficacia.security` or any of its subpackages.

Comment: Spring security scan all your packages when starting up, if your WebMvcConfiguration class outside of the security package, it doesn't recognize by default.

Comment: @AlejoDev Have you tried to take away the `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Comment: @AlejoDev Another question: In which package is your main `Application.java` file (the one that has the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation? Does `@SpringBootApplication` have a `scanBasePackages` attribute?

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt No don't have a scanBasePackages attribute

Comment: In which package is the main Application.java file (the one that has the @SpringBootApplication annotation)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183384/discussion-between-alejodev-and-markus-pscheidt).

Comment: com.eficacia is the package

Answer (score 1):

You are creating bean of type PasswordEncoder and try to autowire BCryptPasswordEncoder

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Change this:

private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

```
public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, 
   BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}
```

to this :
  private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder ;

```
public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, 
   PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder ) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoder ;
}

Spring could not found the BcryptPasswordEncoder type as you are returning PasswordEncoder
```

Comment: @AlejoDev Updated answer

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your help, if I tried it but it did not work I found a very simple way, I simply initialized the object manually using the reserved word new

Comment: @AlejoDevCould you show the sample where it did not work ?)